# Is it possible to track downloads on Android and iOS applications at the same time?

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store-connect

I am trying to track the downloads of an `Android` and `iOS` application at the same time.

**The problem is**: I develop the applications to some clients but I have to upload the applications in their respective `Android`/`iOS` developer accounts. I need to track the visits of each application because they will pay depending of the downloads of the application. All the applications are uploaded to `Google Play` and `iTunes Connect`.

**What I need**: Some way to track downloads on both OS(`Android` and `iOS`) that allow me to track the downloads of the desired applications that are not on my developer accounts.

Is there a way to track the downloads of some applications that are in both `Android` and `iOS`?

**EDIT:** I am trying to track the downloads of an app that is on a third person developer account because I need to track their downloads although they change their password accounts (I have them right now). I prefer not to add additional code to that applications if possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: One approach is to use Firebase Analytics (https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/)

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly Thank you for the recommendation. Is it possible to do it without adding code? I already have uploaded them to their respective developer accounts.

Comment: No, at least not for Firebase....you'll need to re-build/publish apps.

Comment: if you are ok for third party tool try https://www.appannie.com/tours/app-analytics-platform/

Comment: @AmodGokhale Yes, it would be ok but, is it possible to track the downloads of an application that is on a external developer account?

Comment: @Error404 , no you will need access to developer console. You can ask to add your email address as "Release manager" on google console and Add to itunes analytics report users.

Comment: @AmodGokhale And on Google Play what account will be show as the creator of the APP? They want to appear as they have created their applications.

Comment: @Error404 yes keep their account as owner of apps. Just add your email as additional user on Google Play store as type "Release Manager" so that you can view downloads etc, same on itunesconnect. No need to change owner of app

Comment: @AmodGokhale Ok I will investigate about it. Thank you.

Comment: @Error404 If they are not offline apps, you can simply a request to your server. It will be one time request when the user opens the app for the first time. This way, you don't need to add any external library. Please let me know if it's possible for you

Comment: For this, you can handle with API too. Ask your web team for same they will create an API for you and you may handle it easily :-), This is very unlogical solution coz if possible you have to handle it via any Analytics.

Comment: @KrishnaCA I do not exactly understand what do you mean. To send a request to a url the first time on an app it will send the request? Or what do you mean?

Comment: @Arpan24x7 And what should I do creating an API? I just want to know how much downloads the application had. Nothing more.

Comment: @Error404, yes from API you have to generate a report of which device, OS, and APP version is installing your app with time and place too.

Comment: @Error404 when you send a request to server, the data from the request can simply be stored in to your database. Then, you can query the database to get the data regarding number of installs. When the app is launched, you can have simply check whether it's launched for the first time or not by using `NSUserDefaults`. If it's launched for the first time, then send an API request to server. Let me know, it you have any doubts

Comment: You can create your own manual tracker. I do not know if/how you can get the numbers but if you create an app where you input the new installs per day. A setup would then include current active vs total installs

Answer (score 1):

You can track them using any analytics framework, and some health frameworks. Firebase (former google analytics) will do. Fabric will do. Splunk Mint will do. Since all of them are independent of the store account, the only thing you'll need, in general, are the package name, and in some cases, the developer key.

Comment: In all of them I have to write aditional code on the application to make them work, right?

Comment: Depends on the functions you want to track. For installs, usually initialize it (a one liner in the application's onCreate) is enough.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Its not that hard to keep track of your downloads in android]

Google Android Developer cosole automatically does that for you

Comment: Yes, I know that I can use it but I would like a way to monitorize all my apps that are in differents client developer accounts.

Comment: @Error404 Atleast GOOGLE doesn't provide this information with any API due to security reasons.

Comment: @Error404 - Well that will be a security challenge to go through and because of that I don't think google can allow you.

Comment: @Error404
You may like to go through this
**https://developers.google.com/android/**